# Toggle CSS Spoiler button by link

Tags: html, css, ajax

So I have Ajax setup to replace the main div by a link. Though I also have a spoiler type navigation where you can hide or show the menu. Anyhow my links are in this and Im wondering how I can have it so when I click on one of the links it'll toggle the menu and will close it.

```
<input class="spoilerbutton show2" style="width:100%" type="button" value="Show Navigation" onclick="this.value=this.value=='Show Navigation'?'Hide Navigation':'Show Navigation';">
<div class="show2 spoiler"><div>

<nav id="nav" class="show2">
<ul>
<li id="ajax" class="ajax"><a href="index.html" id="ajax" class="ajax skel-panels-ignoreHref">Home</a></li> 
</ul>
</nav>

</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.spoilerbutton {display:block;margin:5px 0;}

.spoiler {color:black;overflow:hidden;background: #f5f5f5;}

.spoiler > div {-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;-moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease;-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;transition: margin 0.2s ease;}

.spoilerbutton[value="Show Navigation"] + .spoiler > div {margin-top:-100%;}

.spoilerbutton[value="Hide Navigation"] + .spoiler {padding:5px;}
```

**Update new code:**

```
<input name="spoilerbtn" name="spoilerbtn" class="spoilerbutton show2" style="width:100%" type="button" value="Show Navigation"  onclick="this.value=this.value=='Show Navigation'?'Hide Navigation':'Show Navigation';">

<div class="show2 spoiler"><div>

<nav id="nav" class="show2">

                            <ul>
                                <li id="ajax" class="ajax"><a href="index.html" onclick="spoilerbutton.value=spoilerbuttonv.value=='Show Navigation'?'Hide Navigation':'Show Navigation';" id="ajax" class="ajax skel-panels-ignoreHref">Home</a></li>




                            </ul>
                        </nav>


</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `onclick="spoilerbtn.value = 'Show Navigation';"` to your link should work. And add `name="spoilerbtn"` to your button.

Comment: But you changed the onclick value I gave you for the link.

Comment: Oh opps. Well I end up fixing and replacing with; onclick="spoilerbtn.value = 'Show Navigation';" but still notihng. Actually im not sure how I got the code like how it was ^

Comment: That's really weird. I copied and pasted your code into a test file and my changes worked for me.

Comment: Really? I'll keep trying then.

Comment: So I've decided to test it on a new .html document, seems like it still does not want to work: http://pastebin.com/YwUWHML1

Comment: Ok, the last suggestion I can make is to add target="_blank" to the link so opening it won't affect the current page.

Comment: "That's really weird. I copied and pasted your code into a test file and my changes worked for me." Could you just paste your code into a pastebin? I just tried adding target="_blank" just opens a new page.. nothing else.